# how to create and access single sign on users using SharePoint 2013?

Tags: single-sign-on

I'm new to SharePoint 2013 technology.
Here is the scenario.

When the application is initiated, user access will be verified by comparing the Single Sign-on User 
(SSO) from the users .Net ID to the Users_tbl table(using sql server). 
 If the user does not have access provide an error message “User does not have access. Please 
contact System Administrator”. 
 If the user is in the users_tbl allow the user to continue.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the User Profile Service is configured the domain users would be able to use SSO feature.

Below steps can be referred for SSO configuration.

Configure and start the Microsoft Single Sign-On service

1. On the server, click Start, Control Panel, Administrative Tools, and then click Computer Management.
2. In the Computer Management console, expand Services and Applications, and then click Services.
3. Right-click Microsoft Single Sign-On Service, and then choose Properties.
4. On the General tab, change the Startup type to Automatic.
5. On the General tab, under Service Status, click Start.
6. Click OK to save your changes and close the Properties window.

For configuring Service the login account must be:domain user account, Office SharePoint Server farm account, member of the Security Administrators role, db_creator role on the computer running Microsoft SQL Server, cannot be a group account.

---

IE Settings:

To enable single sign-on in Internet Explorer, you must add the SharePoint site to your Intranet Sites. To do this:

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Click Tools > Internet Options
3. In the Security tab, select Local intranet and click the Sites button.
4. Click the Advanced button.
5. Enter the address `http://SharePoint` and click Add.
6. Click Close.
7. Click OK.
8. Click OK.

You should also verify that Integrated Windows Authentication is enabled.

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Click Tools > Internet Options
3. Click the Advanced tab.
4. In the Settings panel, scroll to the Security section. Ensure that Integrated Windows Authentication is enabled.

Comment: Hi hardik, thanks for your reply. I had gone through your given steps. I couldnt able to found  Microsoft Single Sign-On Service on Computer Management console. But i can able to see MicrosoftiSNS server. Is that one need to choose. Please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: have you configured User Profile Service?

Comment: yes its configured. but couldnt able to get Microsoft Single Sign-On Service.

Comment: then try on the other domain machine using different login account and the user should be added in sharepoint. it should work

Comment: i checked but still couldnt get it. I have a query. Is webapplication should be in enterprises?